# Excel Conditional Statement to determine which rows to delete and which to keep

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 excel sheets containing data that will help me determine whether or not I need to delete or keep a row. Essentially, the way it works is that I have Column A in both sheets of the data which contains a code and column B of sheet 2 contains either a value of the text "Free". For each code in column A of sheet 1, I want to check if the same code exists in column A of sheet 2, and if so, I want to then look at column B of sheet 2 on that same row, and if it's cell contains "FREE" I would like to delete the entire row in containing that code from sheet 1.

```
Sheet 1:                     Sheet 2:

A      B      C            A      B      C
1234   Data  Data          1234  FREE   Data
1235   Data  Data          1456  Value  Data
1547   Data  Data          1547  Free   Data
1483   Data  Data          1247  Value  Data
```

Then we Would get:

```
Sheet 1:                                Sheet 2:

A      B      C    *Decision        A      B      C
1234   Data  Data   Delete          1234  FREE   Data
1235   Data  Data   Keep            1456  Value  Data
1547   Data  Data   Delete          1547  Free   Data
1483   Data  Data   Keep            1247  Value  Data
```

This is what I have tried, but there is an error here I can't figure out. I am assuming I am doing something wrong with the syntax. HS is the name range of column A of sheet 2

```
=IF((VLOOKUP(A2,HS,1) = A2) and (Vlookup(A2, HS, 2) = "FREE"), "delete", "keep")
```

Comment: removed `vba` tags and replaced with `formula` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below formula. It will work

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0))=FALSE,"Delete","Keep")
```

**Proof of Work**

[image]

**EDIT #1**

As per the request, please see the sheet 2 formula

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,Sheet1!A:A,0))=FALSE,"Delete","Keep")
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome this works... is there a way to edit it to also say "delete" for any codes contained in sheet 1, that are not also found in sheet 2?

Comment: see my EDIT #1. Hope you requesting this

Comment: What I had in mind was combining both the initial solution with the additional request, so that a single formula will check both conditions (if codes in A column from both sheets are the same with column B in sheet 2 being "FREE" AND then also checking if the code in sheet A is not found in sheet 2 in the same formula as being Delete conditions). Is this possible?

Comment: its possible with the helper column in Sheet 2

Answer (score 1):

Your `AND` is in the wrong place. It should start the multiple conditions and each condition needs to be separated by a comma:

```
=IF(AND((VLOOKUP(A2,HS,1) = A2),(Vlookup(A2, HS, 2) = "FREE")), "delete", "keep")
```

Comment: any idea why =Vlookup(A2, HS, 2) would give me #REF! instead of return FREE or any other value contained in column B of sheet 2?

Answer (score 0):

Does this accomplish what you are looking for?

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A3;Sheet2!$A$1:$C$5;2;FALSE)="Free";"delete";"keep");"keep")
```